# Multiple uses of ID to open pop up box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup

I've used this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) to build a pop up box with a contact form however i want to use this in multiple places without duplicating the code and changing the ID's for each button

any advice would be appreciated if you need anymore information please let me know ill edit the question

[here is my site ive added the id to both the slider links](http://live.homesmartenergy.co.uk/)

this is my pop up box and button

```
 <button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-light">
   click here
  </button>
    
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[wpforms id="439"]'); ?>
      </div>
```

here is my javascript

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: For duplicate content use classes instead of `id`. As you've not shown any of the relevant code, we can't give you any specific help on how to do this in your case.

Comment: my code is exactly the same as whats in the tutorial link ive added im trying to add my code now but im having trouble with it

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: You want to use the same modal in multiple places?  Or you want multiple popup boxes (with different content)?

Comment: right ive added the code sorry for the delay everyone

Comment: basically i dont want to uses the modal in multiple places without duplicating and changing ID names how would i do this with classes

Comment: No, you've added the code from w3schools - we can already see that code, we can't see your code that you're "having trouble with" :)

Comment: You *don't* want to re-use the modal?  So you want a second modal and a second button, but don't want to have a second set of code?

Comment: the code ive posted in the question is the code im using i haven't changed it at all except for adding  a shortcode to my contact form

Comment: i want the same modal but that modal will only pop up on one of the two buttons i have it set to and i need that modal to pop up on more buttons

Comment: So you *do* want to reuse the modal (and your comment above was a confusing typo).   In summary:  1 modal, 2 buttons

Comment: ahh yh sorry mate i see that now yes 1 modal, multiple buttons (not just 2)

Comment: 1) Use a class. IDs _must_ be unique. 2) Collect the modals by class with `querySelectorAll()`. 3) Loop through the results of that to add your event handler. All this is well covered on SO and elsewhere. Good luck.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "needs focus" and as duplicates of the things listed above.

Comment: im confused by your answer im not exactly fluent on java script could you show me how to use that method in my code

Comment: can anyone help with this or just point me in the right direction i need the modal to be opened by multiple buttons

Answer (score 0):

Hello thank you for question
Try below code once. Here you find for multiple modals working finely

```js
// Get the modal
function openModal(modal)
{
  var modal = document.getElementById(modal);
    modal.style.display = "block";
    var span = document.querySelector("#"+modal.id+" .close");
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button onclick="openModal('modal1')">Open Modal 1</button>
<button onclick="openModal('modal2')">Open Modal 2</button>

<!-- The Modal 1 -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal1..</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal 2 -->
<div id="modal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal2..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but its not quite what im after as the button i want to put this on is part of a wordpress slider loop I should of said that in my original question however i was just hoping there was just a way to do this with classes rather than ID's as i feel ID's can only be used once where as classes can be used multiple times